# Changing the Value of an XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am converting codes in an XDocument from one format to another. My code looks like this:

```
        if (translate.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XElement element in xml.Descendants())
            {
                if (translate.ContainsKey(element.Value.ToLower()))
                    element.Value = translate[element.Value.ToLower()];
            }
        }
```

The problem is, when I check the value of an XElement that looks like this:

```
<Element>
  <InnerElement>
    <Inner2Element>
      <TargetValue>F-01751</TargetValue> 
    </Inner2Element>
  </InnerElement>
</Element>
```

The value equals F-01751. If I then change it to a new value, my XML looks like this:

```
<Element>NewValue</Element>
```

Is there a way, using XElement, to parse through the XDocument one line at a time rather than recursively? Alternately, is there a way to check the value of only the element being examined, and not any of the child elements? I know I can convert this to an XmlDocument, and accomplish this, but that seems rather extreme. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look for text child nodes (with NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text ) and replace those. These will be of type XText:

```
        if (translate.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XText node in xml.Descendants().Nodes().OfType<XText>())
            {
                if (translate.ContainsKey(node.Value.ToLower()))
                    node.Value = translate[node.Value.ToLower()];
            }
        }
```